# Jarl Dengeir's steward isn't selling the land to build a house in Falkreath

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I sided with the Stormcloaks and Jarl Dengeir is on the throne. He made me his thane and gave me a housecarl, but his steward will not offer to sell the land. Does anyone know what I need to do or what I'm missing? Because I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I believe you might need to speak to the Jarl again to get the house, or do one or more quests for him

Comment: I am already thane and neither him or his steward offer any more missions

Comment: Does anybody know what to do or has anybody else had this problem before

Comment: What system are you playing on? If PC, there might be some command console wizardry to correct this.

Answer (score 3):

The only possible solution is to wait for a few days or reload any save.

Answer (score -1):

Try helping all the people of Falkreath. Worked for my friend

Comment: He's already a thane, Putting Dengeir on the throne is *supposed* to be enough to thane-ship and thus able to purchase land from the steward...